# Is motor imagery a "cognitive function", "cognitive activity", "cognitive action" or just "cognition"

Tags: cognition

Motor imagery involves the imagination of motor movements and is used in motor imagery-based BCI systems. Under what category does motor imagery come under:

1. Cognitive action
2. Cognitive activity
3. Cognitive function
4. Cognition

Comment: Possibly related: [What's the exact definition of a cognitive mechanism?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/27407/7001)

Comment: Why does it matter/why do you want to use one of these phrases/how do you think these terms differ?